Is there a way to run XQuery functions / or XQuery scripts locally within an XSLT script file?
The previous question I made in stack overflow was about how to successfully use load-query-module to run XQuery in XSLT, however the runtime has to be able know how use the location-hint to find the XQuery module to load it.
If I assume my SAP Platform runtime doesn't support this then I need another way to run XQuery within XSLT. Is there away to pass the XQuery as a parameter and then run this within the XSLT or can the XSLT refer to another part of XSLT that has the XQuery embedded elsewhere within the script file?

With Saxon EE (or perhaps PE as well, I haven't checked) there are extension functions like saxon:compile-query https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/functions/saxon/compile-query.html and saxon:query https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/functions/saxon/query.html.

In recent/current versions (11, 12 of Saxon PE/EE) there is also https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/saxon/xquery.html.

Thanks Martin - saxon:compile-query and saxon:query sound like a good way forward for me, are there any small implementation examples of this working in XSLT that you could point me to please?

Here is an example for Saxon 12 (PE/EE) using https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/saxon/xquery.html:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:param name="xquery-param1" as="xs:string" expand-text="no"><![CDATA[
  declare variable $x external; declare variable $y external; <z>{$x + $y + .}</z>
  ]]></xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <result>
      <xsl:variable name="xquery1" select="saxon:xquery($xquery-param1)"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="$xquery1(4, map{xs:QName('x'): 3, xs:QName('y'): 2})"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

And for saxon:compile-query/saxon:query:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:param name="xquery-param1" as="xs:string" expand-text="no"><![CDATA[
  declare variable $x external; declare variable $y external; <z>{$x + $y + .}</z>
  ]]></xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <result>
      <xsl:variable name="xquery1" select="saxon:compile-query($xquery-param1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="xquery1-params" as="element()*">
         <x>3</x>
         <y>2</y>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence select="saxon:query($xquery1,4, $xquery1-params)"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Perfect works fine, thanks Martin, much appreciated for your assistance!

Since working with the above in my debugger I've come across the following issues:

a pre-warning "For parameter  'xquer-param1, the variable/parameter ''$kt' should be placed in a Text Value Template." Then when I start the debugger I get warning "W Evaluation will always throw a dynamic error: Namespace prefix {myfuncs} has not been declared". Any reason for this behaviour in the debugger as doing simple run doesn't yield an issues?

@Alex, it might be better to start a new question for each issue and tag them with saxon (or oxygen, if its about debugging in there).

@Alex, make sure to show all the details, my example doesn't even have a variable kt so your comment so far is hard to relate.
